# Why is an ARP message followed by NTP?

Tags: networking

I just started Wireshark and I wondered why every ARP message is followed by an NTP message? What sense does this make?

However, I also observed that ARP messages are periodically sent. Is there a specific reason for it?

Answer (score 0):

[`ARP`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol) is used to "convert IP addresses to physical addresses" (eg MAC addresses).  If a device wants to reach another device on the local network, it either checks its "ARP resolution cache" (arpcache) or sends an ARP probe.

I think you are probably misinterpreting the correlation between the NTP message and ARP message.  More likely, the device is trying to reach the NTP server, so it sends an ARP probe to resolve the IP address to the MAC address of the server.